# Redirecionamento PHP

Tags: php, redirecionamento

Existe alguma API e/ou função, em PHP, que redirecione as páginas do meu site, conforme a localidade da pessoa ? Exemplo : se não for BR, redireciona para a página em inglês.

Comment: Você é quem deve fazer isso.

Answer (score 2):

O PHP oferece uma função nativa para isso, dê uma olhadinha em [Geo IP Location](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.geoip.php).

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Prefira respostas mais explicativas, não somente baseada num link, se possível com exemplos, pois é o que a maioria dos usuários procura aqui no SO. Só mais uma coisa, olhando rapidamente na documentação apontada, o comentário diz que esta API é depreciada e a versão 2 deve ser usada: [GeoIP2](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php).

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se você possui o módulo [mod_geoip2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) (GeoIP Extension) instalado no seu servidor.

Então, altere seu .htaccess conforme abaixo:

```
 GeoIPEnable On
 GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

 # Start Redirecting countries

# Canada
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://canada.abcd.com$1 [L]

# India
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^IN$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://india.abcd.com$1 [L]

# etc etc etc...
```

A documentação oficial você encontra [Nesse link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)